# Is it possible to create a eye tracking code that can track where the users eye is going across the screen?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently a student making a project that requires eye tracking. I found that most eye tracking codes online only tracks the movement of the face and placement of the eyes. Is it possible to create a code that can track where the eyes are across the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Eye blink detection with OpenCV, Python, and dlib](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/24/eye-blink-detection-opencv-python-dlib/) and [Eye Tracking using OpenCV](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/eye-tracking-using-opencv-2f40cc09183c)

Comment: you'll need very high resolution cameras, or optics that pan/tilt to follow the face/eyes, or cameras screwed to the skull and additional head tracking.

Comment: @nathancy the question is about estimating the direction the eyeballs are pointing. it's not about checking if eyelids are up or down. the second link is a mere regurgitation of code (and an article) by pyimagesearch.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it *possible*

Yes.

> Is it *easy*

No.  Among other things there is research in this for off-boresight targetting of missiles.  Some 'anti-cheating' packages for online testing do something similar, but I've not checked how they work.

Think about it: the problem of working out *where an eye is focusing* is a lot more complicated than tracking *where a face is pointing*.